# Why dielectric polarization is not considered at boundary condition?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Consider the problem of reflection, transmission for incident light at the boundary of two dielectrics.

From Ampere' law, 
 $\vec\nabla\times \vec H = \vec J+\partial\vec D/\partial t $.

Every text book take integral region at boundary of two dielectrics and make the region very narrow so that integral of $ \vec J+\partial\vec D/\partial t $ becomes zero.

However, I cannot understand why $\vec J$ becomes zero.

There is dielectric depolarization at boundary.
So, there is induced charge and thus current exist.

How narrow the integral region is, the amount of dielectric polarization in integral region should not change because dielectric polarization is localized at boundary.

So Why integral of  $ \vec J+\partial\vec D/\partial t $ is zero?

Dielectric polarization parallel to the boundary is already included to dielectric constant ?

Answer (score 0):

The $\vec{J}+\partial\vec{D}/\partial t$ is not necessarily zero, but it is assumed to be finite. Thus if you *integrate* it over vanishingly small area (that *narrow* region) you will get zero. Sometimes people relax this assumption, allowing $\vec{J}$ to diverge at the surface in strictly prescribed fashion. This is how you get surface current density.